# Import 'GoogleMobileAds' not found in Ios (react native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flutter, react-redux

I ran into this error when I install react-native-Admob in my project. Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by just adding two lines in my Pod file.

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform- 
ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'testing' do
config = use_native_modules!

use_react_native!(
:path => config[:reactNativePath],
# to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
:hermes_enabled => false
)

pod 'Interactable', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-interactable'
pod 'react-native-admob', path: '../node_modules/react-native-admob' <======= add this line


target 'lpgTests' do
inherit! :complete
# Pods for testing
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' <====== add this line

end


use_flipper!()

post_install do |installer|
react_native_post_install(installer)
end
end
```

**if you are using M1 Silicon chip you would still get an error & to solve that error you have to run 2 commands**

```
#1 Install ffi

sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

#2 Re-install dependencies

arch -x86_64 pod install
```